# Making a Function, asp?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am trying to make a function to check valid semesters like fall #### or Spring #### and I keep getting this error

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03f6'
>   Expected 'End'
>   Else
>   ^

here is my code...

```
Function IsSemester(UserInput)
' Validation: Spring, Fall

Temp=UserInput

If Len(Temp)=9 Then IsSemester=True

For P=1 to 4

If Left(Temp,P,1)<>"Fall" Then IsSemester=False

Next

If Mid(Temp,5,1)<>" " Then IsSemester=False

For P=6 to 9

If Not IsInteger(Mid(Temp,P,9)) Then IsSemester=False

Next

Else

IsSemester=True 

End If

If Len(Temp)=11 Then IsSemester=True

 For C=1 to 6

If Left(Temp,C,6)<>"Spring" Then IsSemester=False

 Next

If Mid(Temp,7,1)<>" " Then IsSemester=False 

For C=8 to 11

If Not IsInteger(Mid(Temp,8,11)) Then IsSemester=False

Next

Else 

IsSemester=True
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too easy, indent your code and you will find the issue.

```
Function IsSemester(UserInput)
' Validation: Spring, Fall

    Temp=UserInput

    If Len(Temp)=9 Then IsSemester=True

    For P=1 to 4

        If Left(Temp,P,1)<>"Fall" Then IsSemester=False

    Next

    If Mid(Temp,5,1)<>" " Then IsSemester=False

    For P=6 to 9

        If Not IsInteger(Mid(Temp,P,9)) Then IsSemester=False

    Next

    Else

        IsSemester=True 

    End If

    If Len(Temp)=11 Then IsSemester=True

    For C=1 to 6

        If Left(Temp,C,6)<>"Spring" Then IsSemester=False

    Next

    If Mid(Temp,7,1)<>" " Then IsSemester=False 

    For C=8 to 11

        If Not IsInteger(Mid(Temp,8,11)) Then IsSemester=False

    Next

    Else 

        IsSemester=True
    End If
End Function
```

If you use

```
IF Len(temp)=9 Then IsSemester=True
```

means it is a standalone If statement, only the statement after THEN on the same line will be controlled by that condition, therefore the For loop on the next line is a separate statement which is not related to that IF. You should change your code to

```
If Len(Temp)=9 Then
    IsSemester = True

    '<whatever your code here>
End If
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you pointed out the error (specifically), although I strongly agree that the OP should indent his code.

Comment: Can you see the last `Else` and `End If`?? Seems there is a `IF` missing before that...

Comment: **I** see that you fixed the problem.  I meant for the benefit of the OP.  You should always explain your solution, even if it's just briefly.  See point number 10 in this Meta post: [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer/118694#118694)

Comment: I thought the If started with If len(Temp)=11 and the end if ends it. Sorry about indenting I'm a noob...

Comment: @Nick Thanks, I'll remove my downvote (and I'll upvote it actually).  Also, welcome to the site you're kicking butt, 200 rep in 2 weeks =)  PS: If you want to notify someone from your comments, you can use the "@" symbol.  For me that would be `@jadarnel27`.  Just FYI.

Comment: @user1360260, indenting the code is very important for a programmer, it helps you to find out the issues.

Comment: thanks Nick still having some issues but the syntax errors have been fixed